# Pass variable from post to blade form view laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, posting

Hi all I am trying to pass a variable to my post method in my form view
This is my form view updated code

```
{{ 
     Form::open(array(
    'route' => ['faculty/dept2''],
    'method' => 'post',
    'id' => 'form-getdept-setting'))
}}

{{ 
    Form::label( 'faculty_id', 'Faculty Id:' ) 
}}
{{ 
    Form::text( 'faculty_id', '', array(
    'id' => 'faculty_id',
    'placeholder' => 'Enter Faculty Id',
    'maxlength' => 20,
    'required' => true)) 
}}

{{ 
     Form::submit( 'Find Information', array(
    'id' => 'btn-getdeptsetting')) 
}}

{{ 
   Form::close() 
}}
```

This is my controller

```
public function getAllDept2()
{
   if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) 
   {
     return Response::json(array(
    'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'));
   }

$fId = Input::get( 'faculty_id' );

$faculty = Facultyform::where('File_Number', '=', $fId)
->get();

if($faculty[0]['isChair'] == 'Y')
{
$department = $faculty[0]['Home_Department_Desc'];
return $department;
/* $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
var_dump($last_query);
die(); */
}
else{
return Redirect::to('/');
}
}
```

And here are my routes

```
      Route::post('faculty/dept/{department}', array(
    'as' => 'faculty/dept/{department}',
    'uses' => 'FacultyController@getAllDept2'
));
```

```
//faculty get users by department//
 Route::get('faculty/dept/{department}',
    'FacultyController@getAllDept'
    );
```

dd($department) result do show the user's department.

Comment: So what you say is that `$department->department` doesn't get populated as intended? In the line before View::make do a dd($department) then you see if the variable has the data you think it should be there. My guess is either the variable isn't get filled or that $department->department should rather be another column like id.

Comment: Please clean up the code in your question, it's awful.

Comment: I tried dd($department) I posted what I recieved

Comment: when I do a dd($allDEPT2) I get the field I need but when I put that in the view I get Undefined variable: allDEPT2

Comment: I tried ->with("department",$department); and also ->with("allDEPT2", $allDEPT2); same error

Comment: was thinking of doing return Redirect::to('faculty/dept')->with("department",$department);

Comment: Got it to work yessssss!!!! I used Redirect::to("faculty/dept/".$department);

Answer (score 0):

I used the Redirect::to() to pass the variable to the other route

```
public function getAllDept2()
{
if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) 
{
 return Response::json(array(
'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'));
}

$fId = Input::get( 'faculty_id' );

$faculty = Facultyform::where('File_Number', '=', $fId)
->get();

if($faculty[0]['isChair'] == 'Y')
{
$department = $faculty[0]['Home_Department_Desc'];
return Redirect::to('facutly/dept/'.$department);
/* $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
var_dump($last_query);
die(); */
}
else{
return Redirect::to('/');
}
}
```